# Is there a way to append user input text to a file untill an exit character without appending the exit character in JAVA?

Tags: java, file, append

Hello I am trying to append user input to a file untill the user enters an exit character. I have reached to a certain point but the problem i have is that the exit character also gets appended in the text file.
Below is some code concerning the issue.
Thanks in advance.

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    BufferedWriter writer = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;

    try {
        writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\gg\\newfile.txt",true));
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter text to enter file: ");
        //String text = input.nextLine();
        String text = "";
        while(!text.equals("/")){
            text = input.nextLine();
            writer.write(text);
            writer.newLine();
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    writer.close();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the calls to `writer.write();` and `writer.newLine()` in an if clause that checks whether text is equal to the exit character to avoid it being appended to the file.

By the way, string comparisons where you compare a fixed string with a variable of type String should be done the other way around. Call equals on the fixed string and pass the variable as an argument of `equals()`. This is because the variable could be null, and then it would trigger a NullPointerException.